# How to remove a logical volume from xen vm after failed snapshot

Tags: lvm, xen, snapshot

First of I'm fairly new to xen vm technology so sorry in advance if I use the wrong vocabulary. So what happened is I took a snapshot from my vm, after a while a cronjob tried to create a second snapshot which failed since the LVM partion had not enough space. I deleted the manual snapshot from with the XCP-ng Center. But the space was not released.

I used `lvs` and this is what I get (formatted for better readability) :

| LV | VG | Attr | LSize | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MGT | VG_XenStorage-9f728af0-0817-f908-63ae-5a06ce6914fe | -wi-a----- | 4.00m |  |
| VHD-9f6e2f19-1d88-4c26-8de8-9da27c9a99c6 | VG_XenStorage-9f728af0-0817-f908-63ae-5a06ce6914fe | -ri-ao---- | 346.50g |  |
| VHD-f0e775ff-5b43-497d-acbb-419874db1bb1 | VG_XenStorage-9f728af0-0817-f908-63ae-5a06ce6914fe | -wi-ao---- | 350.69g |  |
| 0983d936-77c9-f18a-0014-89b326963425 | XSLocalEXT-0983d936-77c9-f18a-0014-89b326963425 | -wi-ao---- | <5.46t |  |

The dots columns are `Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert` those are all empty. I'm fairly certain that `VHD-9f6e2f19-1d88-4c26-8de8-9da27c9a99c6` is the LV which needs to be removed.

I used `xe vdi-list` and found the vdi corresponding to that LV. This vdi has no vbd assigned and sr-uuid was `<not in database>`, and name-label was `base-copy`. I tried `xe vdi-destroy uuid=$th_uuid`. But it failed with the message: "Can not remove vdi because it is not manged by the system" (I'm not sure this was the exact wording)
I also tried to directly remove the LV but it failed due being in use.

I then did `xe vdi-forget uuid=$the_uuid` hoping that would free the resources / unblock th LV. The VDI is now gone but the LV remains.

I tried `lvremove -f /dev/VG_XenStorage-9f728af0-0817-f908-63ae-5a06ce6914fe/VHD-9f6e2f19-1d88-4c26-8de8-9da27c9a99c6 --config global{metadata_read_only=0}`

But it still fails for being used.
When I do `lsof /dev/VG_XenStorage-9f728af0-0817-f908-63ae-5a06ce6914fe/VHD-9f6e2f19-1d88-4c26-8de8-9da27c9a99c6`
It returns (again formatted)

| COMMAND | PID | USER | FD | TYPE | DEVICE | SIZE/OFF | NODE | NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tapdisk | 28534 | root | 18r | BLK | 253,3 | 0t4218880 | 39811683 | /dev/mapper/VG_XenStorage--9f728af0--0817--f908--63ae--5a06ce6914fe-VHD--9f6e2f19--1d88--4c26--8de8--9da27c9a99c6 |

When I do an `lsof /dev/VG_XenStorage-9f728af0-0817-f908-63ae-5a06ce6914fe/VHD-f0e775ff-5b43-497d-acbb-419874db1bb1` (the LV I don't whant to touch) it shows:

| COMMAND | PID | USER | FD | TYPE | DEVICE | SIZE/OFF | NODE | NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tapdisk | 28534 | root | 17u | BLK | 253,2 | 0t4327936 | 39810421 | /dev/mapper/VG_XenStorage--9f728af0--0817--f908--63ae--5a06ce6914fe-VHD--f0e775ff--5b43--497d--acbb--419874db1bb1 |

Note the same PID, which makes me thing I should not just kill that process.

So any advice on how to deal with that Situation is highly appreciated and if you need more information just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how Xen would work(I'm also new to this kind of thing), I used to remove a logical volume, for example the swap partition:

I would do the following:

```
# lvremove /dev/mapper/vg0-swap
```

but in case it is some other volume I guess you should do the following first:

first, umount the logical volume:

```
# umount /dev/mapper/vg0-var
```

and then:

```
# lvremove /dev/mapper/vg0-var
```

Comment: Unfortunately umount reports the device as not mounted. Also normally the -f parameter should remove the lv even when mounted. But thanks for your input.